# Is possible make comment for file included with assetic?

Tags: symfony, bundling-and-minification, assetic

I have project on Symfony 3 and I installed and started using assetic. So have simply question. Is possible make comment for file included with assetic?

Including files - old way:

```
<!-- Jquery 1.12.4 -->
<script src="{{ asset('assets/jquery-1.12.4/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap - Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="{{ asset('assets/bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Superfish - drop down navigation menu js -->
<script src="{{ asset('assets/super-fish-1.7.7/dist/js/superfish.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Moment.js -  Parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates in JavaScript -->
<script src="{{ asset('assets/moment-2.15.1/moment.js') }}"></script>

...
```

Including files - with assetic: (without any comment to included file)

```
{% javascripts
    'assets/jquery-1.12.4/jquery.min.js'
    'assets/bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'
    'assets/super-fish-1.7.7/dist/js/superfish.js'
    'assets/moment-2.15.1/moment.js'   

    ...    
%}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Comment: You dont wanna do that. From the Symfony documentation it reads "In the dev environment, each file is still served individually, so that you can debug problems more easily. However, in the prod environment (or more specifically, when the debug flag is false), this will be rendered as a single script tag, which contains the contents of all of the JavaScript files."

Comment: So to clarify my answer, once you put your project in production mode, all your JavaScript files are merged into one big file. No need to individual them individually.

Comment: Yes you are probably right. I just wanted it to yourself for clearer surce code...